# Visual Studio doesn't highlight my new classes in Xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Sometimes my class is becoming highlighted for a few second but soon the problem shows again. I tried build cleaaning, restoring visual studio, deleting my pages as I saw some people had similar issues and it was because of the xaml files.
Everything was great until last week.

I haven't noticed the reason of this bug. Also i tried using different namespaces and changed some folders, created new classes. Nothing helped

Please help me fix it as I have a lot of code to be done and my inspiration dies every time I see my class with white color)

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: I have lately seen the same in Razor pages, using VS 2022. Seems they have changed the coloring and introduced a bug. Which VS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2019

Comment: You could report it on visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears while using XamarinCommunityToolkit since version 1.3.2
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1815

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).